# UML Class Diagram - Multiple Associations

Tags: java, uml, diagram, class-diagram

an UML class diagram that pictures an high school administration system is required.

- Pupils and Teachers derive from Person
- each Pupil belongs to 1 (School)Class
- each class has btw 10-25 students
- each Teacher has >= 1 Certificate to teach a (School)Subject

[image: [Draft of Elements]]

further, it is asked to design the following:

> a) which Teacher, teaches which Class, in which Subject, for how many
>   hours/week? 
>  b) is there a safe way to assure that a Teacher only
>   teaches Subjects he has a Certificate for?

after fuzzing around several hours i came up with this: [image: [Complete Draft]].

but i still can not imagine how to design the diagram in a way that all (or at least three) of the conditions from **a)** are presented as required.

is there actually a way to do so in a UML *class* diagram?

**edit:** after reading Ayo Ks comment i came up with this: [image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an association class with a constraint.

[image]

Comment: thanks! but, is this a standard UML class diagram annotation? this way it seems very logic to me. i would love to write it like that.  just, is this an 'official' solution?

Comment: This is _official_ notation. The constraint is OCL. Can't say much about it (not fluent in that), but it looks ok.

Comment: @tingtong OCL is a language to define constraints, it is not part of UML but it used to defined constraints on model. OCL is defined by OMG as UML.

Comment: @granier which program did u use for that diagram? thanks

Comment: @tingtong EA but association class is part of UML and should be available in all tools ...

Answer (score 1):

> which Teacher, teaches which Class, in which Subject, for how many hours/week?

This means that what binds the teacher to a class is a Subject. Since there are multiple subjects, a teacher will have a property that represents a list of subject, and a class will also have a list of subjects. For representing how many hours/week, this will be tied to the subject. A subject should have a property representing how many hours it should last and a property representing how many times a week it is taught. This way once a teacher teaches a subject, by getting the subject the teacher takes, you can pick out how many times a week and how may hours

> b) is there a safe way to assure that a Teacher only teaches Subjects
>   he has a Certificate for?

For this since a certification is tied to a subject, things will change a bit. This will mean that a Teacher will no longer have a List of subjects as a property but rather a list of certifications, so by getting the certifications a teacher has, you can get the subject(s) the teacher can take from the certifications and the number of hours/week the teacher takes the subject

Hope this helps you in finishing your diagram.